# как сложить все числа которые ниже 1000

Tags: c#, массивы, linq

```c
int[] salary = { 231, 1123, 321, 23112};
```

Comment: В чём у вас сложность? Тут не учат языкам с нуля. Вы должны хоть что-то попытаться и сделать сами сначала.

Comment: На листочке можете попробовать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для получения элементов удовлетворяющих условию используется метод `.Where`.
Для получения суммы элементов - метод [`.Sum`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-sum(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-int32))))

```
var sum = salary.Where(el => el < 1000).Sum();
```